# How to fetch the cause for the cancellation of the Docusign envelope?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I would like to know if I can get the reason why the signatory rejected the envelope via api.

I'm using this call:

```
public function buscaDadosEnvelope(){
    # Call API method
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->token);
    $api_client = new ApiClient($config);
    $envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);

    $results = $envelope_api->getEnvelope( env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), $this- 
    >envelope_id);
    return $results;
 }
```

It does not return the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the envelope audit trail. It's a list of events in the audit of the envelope. See this blog post on how to do this - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-parsing-envelopes-audit-events

You will have to then search for the void/cancel reason in the list of events and it will include the reason.